# problems with str_replace not working properly

Tags: php

I'm making a form text input box for an inventory list. I type everything into the form and it breaks everything down to be put into SQL(not at the SQL part yet).

Input would look something like this

5-1 1/2 black 90° sch 40 (have 10 of the sch 80 ones)

amount - size - fitting name ( comments)

I got everything in their own variable now I just need to remove the "(comments)" part from the fitting name. str_replace should do the trick but it seems to only work "some times" ? I'm not sure why it doesn't always work. The picture below show that it only worked 2 times. As for my regex, I'm really bad at them. lol Thanks for any help you can give with my little problem.  [image]

```
foreach ($components as $value) {
    $value=stripslashes($value);
            // get rid of empty lines       
             if  (empty($value)) { continue; }
            // will Split the amount of fittings from the value.
            $quantity = explode("-", $value);
            //Will split the name of the fitting and also give the size of the fittings.
            $test=preg_split('/([a-w]|[A-W])/', $quantity[1],2, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
            //split the comments from the fitting name.
            $comments = explode("(", $test[2]);
            //removes the remaining ) from the left side
            $comments =preg_replace("/\)/", "" , $comments[1]);
 
                    if(!empty($comments)) {
                        $fitting_name = str_replace("($comments)","", $test[1].$test[2]);
                        }else{
                        $fitting_name = $test[1].$test[2];
                        }
        // The table format is just to make sure everything is working right before inputting into SQL
 echo "
  <tr>
    <td>$value</td>
    <td>". $quantity[0] ."</td>
    <td>$test[0]</td>
    <td>$fitting_name</td>
    
    <td>$comments  </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

";          
        
}
  echo "</tr>
</table>";
}
```

Input

```
0-1/2 PP union 
1- 1 1/2x1 1/4 copper PP fitting red
9- 1 1/2" copper PP 90°
5-2" copper PP 90°    (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) 
13-2" copper PP Tee (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) 
10-1*1*3/4 copper PP tee


60- 3/4"  PP cap and chain value 
50 - 3/4" PP value (we only have 4 more)
19- 3/4" threaded cap and chain value 
0-2" threaded value 
0- 2 1/2" threaded value (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) 


5- 3/4" black Street 90°
0 - 3/4 black union 
0- 1" black union 
0-1" black tee 
1 - 1 1/2 black union 
6-1 1/4 black cap
7-1 1/2" * 1" black bushing
3 - 1 1/2 black coupling 
5-1 1/2 black 90° sch 40? (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) 



4 - 3/8" rod 6'
4-3/8" rod 10'
6 - 1/2" rod 6'
0-5/8" rod 6"
0-5/8" rod 10'
0-3/4 rod 6'
2 - 1" rod 6'(have 10 of the sch 80 ones)
```

Comment: What is your expected output? I'm having a hard time identifying cases where you say it doesn't work.

Comment: I needed to remove the "(have 10 of the sch 80 ones)" from the fitting name column. The code I had only worked 2 times out of the 6 times for some reason. Ken Lee was able to make it work by adding trim to the str_replace. Not sure why that worked just yet, will have to ask him later.

Comment: @SnakZMaynard because there are spaces in excess. `"(foo bar)     "`. You remove the parenthesis to get `"foo bar"` and then you replace that with parenthesis. In my example, you get  `"(foo bar)     "` and try to replace  `"(foo bar     )"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first remove the comment before doing any parsing, to cleanse the input.

You can extract it with a RegEx :

```
\s*\(.*?\)
```

`\s*` matches 0 or more white spaces

`\(` matches a parenthesis

`.*?` matches any characters (lazy match)

`\)` matches a parenthesis

Now, you can replace this by an empty string :

```
<?php
$input = [
    "0-1/2 PP union ",
    "1- 1 1/2x1 1/4 copper PP fitting red",
    "9- 1 1/2\" copper PP 90°",
    "5-2\" copper PP 90°    (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) ",
    "13-2\" copper PP Tee (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) ",
    "10-1*1*3/4 copper PP tee",
    "",
    "",
    "60- 3/4\"  PP cap and chain value ",
    "50 - 3/4\" PP value (we only have 4 more)",
    "19- 3/4\" threaded cap and chain value ",
    "0-2\" threaded value ",
    "0- 2 1/2\" threaded value (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) ",
    "",
    "",
    "5- 3/4\" black Street 90°",
    "0 - 3/4 black union ",
    "0- 1\" black union ",
    "0-1\" black tee ",
    "1 - 1 1/2 black union ",
    "6-1 1/4 black cap",
    "7-1 1/2\" * 1\" black bushing",
    "3 - 1 1/2 black coupling ",
    "5-1 1/2 black 90° sch 40? (have 10 of the sch 80 ones) ",
    "",
    "",
    "",
    "4 - 3/8\" rod 6'",
    "4-3/8\" rod 10'",
    "6 - 1/2\" rod 6'",
    "0-5/8\" rod 6\"",
    "0-5/8\" rod 10'",
    "0-3/4 rod 6'",
    "2 - 1\" rod 6'(have 10 of the sch 80 ones) "
];

foreach ($input as $value)
{
    $newValue = preg_replace("#\s*\(.*?\)#", "", $value);
    echo $newValue . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Output :

```
0-1/2 PP union 
1- 1 1/2x1 1/4 copper PP fitting red
9- 1 1/2" copper PP 90°
5-2" copper PP 90° 
13-2" copper PP Tee 
10-1*1*3/4 copper PP tee


60- 3/4"  PP cap and chain value 
50 - 3/4" PP value
19- 3/4" threaded cap and chain value 
0-2" threaded value 
0- 2 1/2" threaded value 


5- 3/4" black Street 90°
0 - 3/4 black union 
0- 1" black union 
0-1" black tee 
1 - 1 1/2 black union 
6-1 1/4 black cap
7-1 1/2" * 1" black bushing
3 - 1 1/2 black coupling 
5-1 1/2 black 90° sch 40? 



4 - 3/8" rod 6'
4-3/8" rod 10'
6 - 1/2" rod 6'
0-5/8" rod 6"
0-5/8" rod 10'
0-3/4 rod 6'
2 - 1" rod 6'
```

[Try it yourself](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e4210a86f324373da3812ae3dbf32f528776292)

Comment: Was at work for a pretty long time so wasn't able to really test it until know.
Your way of solving the problem is a much better way as like you said, it deals with a problem I may end up having down the road. Thank you for the help Cid.

Answer (score 2):

Plese try changing the following line

```
$fitting_name = str_replace("($comments)","", $test[1].$test[2]);
```

to

```
$fitting_name = str_replace("(" . trim($comments).")","", $test[1].$test[2]);
```

and see the effect. Please let us know the result.

Comment: that did the trick i only needed to change one thing as it was cutting out a latter. 
change 
$test[1]." " . $test[2]  
to
 $test[1].$test[2]

Comment: good to know that  you have fixed the problem. Please mark it answered so that we can close this one.

Comment: This will work as long as there isn't something like `"(   hello world   )"`